# IOS App store build upload showing processing and got rejected with errorr "There was an error importing this build. View all builds in Activity."

Tags: swift, ios8, app-store, app-store-connect

I am working an app on Objective-C supports IOS7+. It has also today widget. We recently written a new new feature in swift.

Now when we are uploading the build to ituens connect with providing support IOS8+ only. we faced some errors, which we resolved.
And still Its showing a warning that 
"The archive passed validation with several warnings. 
Itunes store operation succeded with a warning. 
the resulting api analysis file is too large. we were unable to validate your API usage prior to delivery. This is just an informational message".

After we uploading the build to ituens connect. the status showing processing. After some time its get rejected.

If we submit with out swift code. Its been working.

How do we know why its get rejected. Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:** The message showing in Ituens connect is "There was an error importing this build. View all builds in Activity."
[image: Warning Screen]

Comment: You will need to contact Apple directly to get advice on why they rejected your app.

Comment: @remus is there any logging stuff in iTunes connect or any other.